# Pandas to datetime

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, format

I have a date that is formatted like this:
01-19-71
and 71 is 1971 but whenever to_datetime is used it converts is to 2071! how can I solve this problem? I am told that this would need regex but I can't imagine how since there are many cases in this data

my current code:

```py
    re_1 = r"\d{1,2}[/-]\d{1,2}[/-]\d{2,4}"
    re_2 = r"(?:\d{1,2} )?(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)[a-z]*[ \-\.,]+(?:\d{1,2}[\w]*[ \-,]+)?[1|2]\d{3}"
    re_3 = r"(?:\d{1,2}/)?[1|2]\d{3}"

    # Correct misspillings
    df = df.str.replace("Janaury", "January")
    df = df.str.replace("Decemeber", "December")

    # Extract dates
    regex = "((%s)|(%s)|(%s))"%(re_1, re_2, re_3)
    dates = df.str.extract(regex)

    # Sort the Series
    dates = pd.Series(pd.to_datetime(dates.iloc[:,0]))
    dates.sort_values(ascending=True, inplace=True)
```

Comment: A possible fix could be: `if date_year > current_year: date_year-=100`. Covers the case if the dates don't reach into the future.

Comment: @Claudio thank you, I thought the same but the instructor mentioned that this issue can be solved by using regex and it got me confused

Comment: There is *no way* to know from year specified only as 22 without any further hints if it means 1922 or 2022 or 1822 or 3022, ... So there is as consequence actually **no general solution** to the 'problem'.

Comment: The millenium bug all over again! Do you know what is the lowest year in your dataset?

Answer (score 0):

Considering that one has a string as follows

```
date = '01-19-71'
```

In order to convert to datetime object where 71 is converted to 1971 and not 2071, one can use [`datetime.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) as follows

```
import datetime as dt

date = dt.datetime.strptime(date, '%m-%d-%y')

[Out]:
1971-01-19 00:00:00
```